# jQuery and dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm rendering Google Maps markers with gmap3 jQuery plugin.
I'm triggering marker popups with clicks on menu links based on marker ID, which I can set with this plugin.

Marker gets ID (beside lat/long and popup text) with this code:

```
{latLng:[46.055221,14.504265], data:"some text", id:"map-1"}
```

Marker popup is triggered with this jQuery code:

```
$('#maptrigger-1').live('click',function(){
    var marker = $('#googlemap').gmap3({ get: { id: 'map-1' } });
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click'); 
});
```

and this HTML code:

```
<a href="#" id="maptrigger-1">click</a>
```

I don't want to repeat jQuery code for every marker/ID (map-1/maptrigger-1, map2/maptrigger2, map3/maptrigger3), but I wasn't successful so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)**

```
$('[id^="maptrigger"]').live('click',function(){
```

And better to attach the events using `.on()` as `.live()` has been deprecated as of `jQuery 1.7.0`

```
$('[id^="maptrigger"]').on('click',function(){
```

Comment: `live` has been deprecated.

Comment: @DanielA.White Strange... I thought it was _only_ superseeded, not deprecated.

Comment: @JanDvorak read the docs http://api.jquery.com/live/  `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().`

Comment: @wirey do you know _why_ it was deprecated?

Comment: @JanDvorak the doc states why it shouldn't be used - the drawbacks of using it

Comment: @wirey I've just re-read the docs. I thought `live` was just an alias for `on`, unworthy of any deprecation. It's _this_ beast, doing useless selection. - no wonder it's been deprecated.

Comment: note that this rewrite to `on` will not perform any delegation.

Comment: Removed comment, I've answered too soon. Will report back

Comment: Ok, it's working, thanks guys!
Although I had to use .live(), I don't know why .on() isn't working.
This is the code:
`$('[id^="maptrigger"]').live('click',function(){
var mapid = 'map-' + this.id.split('-')[1],
marker = $('#googlemap').gmap3({ get: { id: mapid } });
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
});`

Comment: .on() will only work for jQuery version 1.7.0 and above.. What is the jquery version you are using

Answer (score 5):

You should put a class to the clickable elements

```
<a href="#" id="maptrigger-1" class="trigger">click</a>
```

and use

```
$('someParentOfAll.triggerElements').on('click','.trigger', function(){
    var mapid = 'map-' + this.id.split('-')[1],
        marker = $('#googlemap').gmap3({ get: { id: mapid } });

    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click'); 
});
```